# Intellij, refactor derived classes to extend from different class

Tags: intellij-idea, structural-search

I have a object oriented structure of a base classes, with about 10 classes deriving from that base class. I wish to specialize it, and need to change what class those 10 classes extend from.

So, I have:

```
B
One extends B
Two extends B
Three extends B
...
```

I need to change this to:

```
B
B2 extends B
One extends B2
Two extends B2
Three extends B2
...
```

Instead of manually going through the classes, does Intellij have a refactoring feature, that lets me change all classes that are derived from B, to derive from B2 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Structural Search & Replace. Search for:

```
class $A$ extends B {}
```

Replace with:

```
class $A$ extends B2 {}
```

Comment: I was not aware of the "Structural Search" and "Structural Search & Replace" features. Just tried it out, and it's even smarter than I anticipated. It looks like $A$ automatically makes it available as a variable that you connect different search parameters to. I can imagine all kinds of uses for this. Thanks for making me aware of this. This is yet another reason I'm liking Intellij more and more.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a global search and replace and just change "extends B" to "extends B2".

But there is also a cleaner way.

- Rename class B to be class B2, now all inherits from B2
- Then add "extends B" and create class B (available as a quick fix)
- Run the refactoring "pull members up" from within B2, choose whatever methods you would like to move to B.

Comment: I ended up doing those thing, but it involved some manual work getting everything right. I was looking for something smart that I thought an IDE's refactoring tricks would probably have. Bas, above, pointed me to this "Structural Search" and "Structural Search & Replace" features, which is even smarter than I anticipated.